# Can mental state affect allergies?

Tags: psychiatry, immune-system

I have heard see this [sketchy reference](http://www.deeptrancenow.com/exc2_multiplepersonality.htm) that people with Multiple Personality Disorder, or other mental disorders, have different physical features when having different personalities. For example, their allergies will change.

Is it true that people's senstivity to allergens can change this way? What is the source for this belief?

Comment: My allergies sure affect my mental state.

Comment: Psychosomatic effects do exist. So it's at the very least plasible. Would be nice to see if there's any sort of research.